# ORACLE DB INSTALLATION : INS-32101 Specified Oracle Home user does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to install Oracle Database.ı DOWNLOADED Oracle Database 19c Grid Infrastructure (19.3) for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit). But in **Oracle Home User** page, when I select **Use Existing Windows User**, and I entered  my Windows Account credentials (username & password ) , **[INS-32101] Specified Oracle Home user does not exist.** error seems.If I try to enter a different username and password this time **[INS-32101] Specified Oracle Home user does not exist.** error occurs. How can I solve this problem?

> INS-32101 Specified Oracle Home user does not exist.     Cause - You
> have selected an Oracle Home user that does not exist.
> Action - Make sure you specify an existing user for Oracle Home
> user.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnqp9.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnqp9.png)

[image: ERROR TAKEN]

Comment: I recommend internal user 'oracle' (or Built-in account) instead of your personal account for an Oracle database.

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried Domscheit  :)  but as user privileges are different for each of them, it would be better if I were manage to choose this.

Comment: Are you going to use RAC? if not why are you installing Grid Infra? (I ask because the title of the question is Oracle DB installation, Not Oracle GI installation)

Comment: Thanks to you, @gsalem , I realized that I chose the wrong option when installing it and installed the wrong thing :) I must fix it first then

Comment: @gsalem - while it is most likely true that the OP is confused about GI vs. database, there _is_ a perfectly legitimate reason for installing GI even if you are not using RAC.  I have an installation like that (well, two if you count both prod and dev).  We do it so that we can use ASM, even without RAC.  ASM has distinct advantages apart from RAC.

Comment: @EdStevens, I totally agree with you: GI can bring lots of features to a single-instance case. My comment was because the question was not directly related to the problem, and installing GI has different requirements than just installing DB.